# Using Embedded Metric Format for logging errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, axios, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using [AWS EMF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Embedded_Metric_Format_Specification.html) to track request durations like so:

```
log.info("track those network dependencies", {
  duration: ret.duration,
  functionName: context.functionName,
  hostname: new URL(url).hostname,
  _aws: {
    Timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
    CloudWatchMetrics: [
      {
        Namespace: "ytemf",
        Dimensions: [["functionName", "hostname"]],
        Metrics: [
          {
            Name: "duration",
            Unit: "Milliseconds",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

Source: https://github.com/kaihendry/yt-aws-emf/blob/main/hello-world/app.js

This works great, and we can see the average duration per hostname in AWS's Cloudwatch Console.

Now there is a **new requirement**, to track errors and time outs. I'm puzzled how to do this. Do I just log 1 for every error? Sum up for retries? What is best practice?

Comment: I think I see how to log errors now https://github.com/awslabs/aws-embedded-metrics-node/issues/99

Answer (score 0):

```js
try {
  const ret = await axios(url);
  metrics.putMetric(ret.status, ret.duration, Unit.Milliseconds);
} catch (error) {
  metrics.putMetric(error.response.status, error.duration, Unit.Milliseconds);
}
```

I map the http response status code to a Metric name:

[image]

So now I can see duration, URL, and varied response codes in one place.